# Retrieve average value of variable with condition dependent on other table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the average of a variable in a table b dependent on distinct values of a variable in another table c based on a condition.

I managed to retrieve the distinct values of table c and to add the where clause. But I only get the result for the first first distinct value.

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.VAR1),
    ITERVAR
FROM TableC C, TableB B
WHERE C.ID = B.ID AND C.ITERVAR IN (SELECT DISTINCT(C.ITERVAR) AS ITERVAR
                                    FROM TableC C WHERE WHERECLAUSE)
AND
WHERECLAUSE;
```

The expected result is:

```
VAR1        | ITERVAR
AVG value 1 | iter value 1
AVG value 2 | iter value 2
....
AVG value N | iter value N
```

I get:

```
VAR1        | ITERVAR
AVG value 1 | iter value 1
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: Because `AND WHERECLAUSE;` must be `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partially corrected query, mainly because you did not show us your full code.  It looks like you should be aggregating by the `ITERVAR` column, so try adding a `GROUP BY` clause to do that:

```
SELECT
    AVG(b.VAR1),
    ITERVAR
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableC b
    ON b.id = c.id AND
       c.ITERVAR IN (SELECT DISTINCT(x.ITERVAR) AS ITERVAR
                     FROM TableC x WHERE WHERECLAUSE) AND
<WHERECLAUSE>
GROUP BY
    ITERVAR;
```

Actually, your current query would not run on most other database, nor on certain server modes in MySQL.  It makes no sense because you are selecting an average, taken over the entire table, along with a single (non aggregate) column value `ITERVAR`.  It is not clear *which* value of `ITERVAR` you would expect MySQL to give you from all values in the entire table.  But adding `GROUP BY` makes a lot more sense here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to solve my problem with it, but without the explicit inner join.